# Why value is null in awk?

Tags: awk, null, sh

Τhis is printed!
Why value is null in awk?

Using awk, how would I assign a value to id?

```
declare id=8853
awk 'BEGIN{if($id==8853){print "null"}}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly change your awk to following it should fly then.

```
awk -v id="$id" 'BEGIN{if(id==8853){print "null"}}'
```

***Explanation:*** In `awk` variables wouldn't work by using `$` which we use in shell to get values for variables in it, here we need to define variables by using `-v variable_name`. So once you define variable with `-v variable_name` we can initialize an `awk` variable to have the value of a shell variable`-v variable_name="$shell variable"`

Answer (score 1):

Please use `-v` parameter for awk. This parameter can be used to pass shell variables to awk.

Do NOT use `$xxx` in awk script directly which is quoted by single quotation marks. Shell does not replace `$xxx` to its value in strings which quoted by single quotation marks.

Ex:

```
declare id=8853
awk -v id="$id" 'BEGIN{if(id==8853){print "null"}}'
```